# Dynamic Island SwiftUI Animations

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios-animations, dynamic-island, activitykit

How can I implement swiftUI animations on a dynamic island icon? I want to do this:

```swift
DynamicIsland() { ... } 
compactLeading: {
  Image("my-icon").shineEffect()
} compactTrailing: {
  Image("my-icon")
}
```

Where in shine effect I start the animation on `onAppear`:

```swift
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
  content
    .onAppear() { 
      startAnimation()
    }
}
```

In the main app it works, but in the dynamic island it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation explicitly states that standard animations don‘t work. You can only animate content-state update using

> built-in transitions: opacity, move(edge:), slide, push(from:), or
> combinations of them. Additionally, request animations for timer text
> with numericText(countsDown:).

Comment: How does PixelPal app animate their graphic in dynamic island and live activity?

Comment: It looks like the content state is updated every second or so with different sprites of the pixel pal which makes it seem like it's animated?